# touching a sprite in cocos2D crashs my app

Tags: iphone, xcode, crash, cocos2d-iphone, touch

well I have a problem with my code :

```
- (void)ccTouchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
UITouch* myTouch = [touches anyObject];
CGPoint location = [myTouch locationInView: [myTouch view]];
location = [[CCDirector sharedDirector]convertToGL:location];
CGRect MoveableSpriteRect =CGRectMake(oeuf1.position.x -(oeuf1.contentSize.width/2),oeuf1.position.y-(oeuf1.contentSize.height/2),oeuf1.contentSize.width,oeuf1.contentSize.height);

if (CGRectContainsPoint(MoveableSpriteRect, location)) {
    [self removeChild:oeuf1 cleanup: YES];
    [self removeChild:ombreOeuf1 cleanup: YES];
}
}
```

When I touch **oeuf1** it disappear like I wanted but then if i touch the screen again my app crash I don't know why ? how can I solve this please ? thank you . Sorry for my english I'm french :/

Comment: Can you give some information about the crash?  What does the debugger say?

Comment: My app stop and quite that's all I know

Comment: Set a breakpoint and step through and examine the values to discover where it goes wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line `CGRect MoveableSpriteRect =CGRectMake(oeuf1.position.x -(oeuf1.contentSize.width/2),oeuf1.position.y-(oeuf1.contentSize.height/2),oeuf1.contentSize.width,oeuf1.contentSize.height);` is still referencing `oeuf1` once it has been removed, and so will cause an `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` error. The simplest way to fix it is to declare a `BOOL` in your header file, and set it to `YES`/`true` when you remove `oeuf1` and `ombreOeuf1`. Then if the `BOOL` is true, don't run

```
CGRect MoveableSpriteRect =CGRectMake(oeuf1.position.x -(oeuf1.contentSize.width/2),oeuf1.position.y-(oeuf1.contentSize.height/2),oeuf1.contentSize.width,oeuf1.contentSize.height);

if (CGRectContainsPoint(MoveableSpriteRect, location)) {
    [self removeChild:oeuf1 cleanup: YES];
    [self removeChild:ombreOeuf1 cleanup: YES];
}
```

EDIT:

In your `.h` file add:

```
@interface .... {
    ...
    BOOL oeuf1Removed; // Feel free to translate this to French!
}
```

And then change `-touchesBegan` to:

```
- (void)ccTouchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch* myTouch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint location = [myTouch locationInView:[myTouch view]];
    location = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL:location];
    if (!oeuf1Removed) {
        CGRect MoveableSpriteRect = CGRectMake(oeuf1.position.x -(oeuf1.contentSize.width/2),oeuf1.position.y-(oeuf1.contentSize.height/2),oeuf1.contentSize.width,oeuf1.contentSize.height);

        if (CGRectContainsPoint(MoveableSpriteRect, location)) {
            [self removeChild:oeuf1 cleanup: YES];
            [self removeChild:ombreOeuf1 cleanup: YES];
            oeuf1Removed = YES;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by don't run how can I do this with code please .I'm french so I could understand a code better

Comment: Pas de problème - j'espère que tous va bien. (Sorry if the French is wrong!)

Comment: do you have a response to this :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9505792/create-shapes-layer-in-cocos2d

Answer (score 0):

do this

```
if (oeuf1) {
CGRect MoveableSpriteRect = CGRectMake(oeuf1.position.x -(oeuf1.contentSize.width/2),
                                       oeuf1.position.y-(oeuf1.contentSize.height/2),
                                       oeuf1.contentSize.width,oeuf1.contentSize.height);
}
```

instead of just

```
CGRect MoveableSpriteRect = CGRectMake(oeuf1.position.x -(oeuf1.contentSize.width/2),
                                       oeuf1.position.y-(oeuf1.contentSize.height/2),
                                       oeuf1.contentSize.width,oeuf1.contentSize.height);
```

if you want the cause of the problem look @ the below answer