# create shapes layer in cocos2D

Tags: iphone, xcode, cocos2d-iphone, calayer, shapes

well in my UIkit app I used this code:

```
boxPath = CGPathCreateMutable();

CGPathMoveToPoint(boxPath, nil, center.x , center.y - 35);
CGPathAddArcToPoint(boxPath, nil, center.x + 35, center.y - 35, center.x + 35, center.y + 35, 4.7);
CGPathAddArcToPoint(boxPath, nil, center.x + 35, center.y + 35, center.x - 35, center.y + 35, 4.7);
CGPathAddArcToPoint(boxPath, nil, center.x - 35, center.y + 35, center.x - 35, center.y, 4.7);
CGPathAddArcToPoint(boxPath, nil, center.x - 35, center.y - 35, center.x, center.y - 35, 4.7);

CGPathCloseSubpath(boxPath);
```

to create a shape, thus I had a layer with a precise shape that I had drawn. How can I do the same thing in cocos2D please? Thank you. Sorry for my english I'm french :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is draw that path to a `CGContext` and set the resulting image to a `CCSprite`:

```
CGSize size = CGSizeMake(width, height); // width and height should be predefined
CGPoint center = CGPointMake(size.width/2, size.height/2); // change this to change where the shape is positioned inside the image (normally will be this value)
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, NO, 0);

CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 1); // Replace 1 with your desired line width
CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(context, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0); // Change RGBA values if needed

CGMutablePathRef boxPath = CGPathCreateMutable();

CGPathMoveToPoint(boxPath, nil, center.x , center.y - 35);
CGPathAddArcToPoint(boxPath, nil, center.x + 35, center.y - 35, center.x + 35, center.y + 35, 4.7);
CGPathAddArcToPoint(boxPath, nil, center.x + 35, center.y + 35, center.x - 35, center.y + 35, 4.7);
CGPathAddArcToPoint(boxPath, nil, center.x - 35, center.y + 35, center.x - 35, center.y, 4.7);
CGPathAddArcToPoint(boxPath, nil, center.x - 35, center.y - 35, center.x, center.y - 35, 4.7);

CGPathCloseSubpath(boxPath);

CGContextAddPath(context, boxPath);
CGContextStrokePath(context);

UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
CCTexture2D *texture = [[CCTexture2D alloc] initWithImage:image];
CCSprite *sprite = [CCSprite spriteWithTexture:texture];
[texture release];

[self addChild:sprite];
```

Comment: how can I define width and height please ? soory but I'm new to cocos2D

Comment: `CGFloat width = 45; // Whatever you want`

Comment: And `CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(context, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);` sets it to solid black.

Comment: I have some errors: Request for member center in something and Too few arguments to function 'CGContextAddPath and expected ] before texture at this line of code : CCSprite *sprite = [CCSprite spriteWithTexture texture];

Comment: sorry but nothing appears on the screen and I have warnings :/ do you tried it on xcode ? you'll see my problem. I have warnings like : passing argument 1 of 'CGPathMoveToPoint' discards qualifiers from pointer target type

Comment: Ok, try my latest edit. If I'm going to be honest it sounds like you don't really know what you're talking about. I strongly urge you to play around with cocos2d and Objective-C, following some tutorials but also trying things yourself, and really try to solve the problems yourself. It will make you much better. Plus if you can't notice that you need to add the sprite as a child to a layer then I don't know what of cocos2d you do understand.

Comment: In which case I do apologise for my comment. Have you set its position? Do you get any more warnings?

Comment: And you need width and height both >= 70, otherwise the lines will be drawn outside the context.

Comment: Oh my god :/ I 'm so sorry the problem was just the color I forgot to change the values you gave me . Sorry :/ but now it works thank you :)

Comment: That's fine - glad we got there! :)

Comment: can you respond to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9558245/add-animation-to-a-shape-in-cocos2d if you can